# Tooltip with image in treemap in r

Tags: r, tooltip, treemap

How can I make a tooltip with image in treemap with r?

I suspect that I will need to use d3.js.

I am using a gvisTreeMap().

Comment: I think it would be prudent for you to review [how to make a a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if it is helpful

```
svg(filename="file1.svg")
devSVGTips("file1.svg", width=9, height=9, toolTipMode=1, title="")
treemap(datafile,.....)
dev.off()
```